# does this error affect my code.?

Tags: javascript

i m getting error in firebug console

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "'Invalid save data.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" nsresult: "0x8057001e (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_STRING)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://firebug/content/spy.js :: callPageHandler :: line 744" data: no]
```

When i put this code

```
value = key+'^_^'+value;
```

But when i modify this code and put

```
value = key
```

the error removes.

so does this error affect my code?

Comment: Duh, it's an error for crying out loud.

Comment: Apparently it does.  You already answered your own question.

Comment: Or your code affects some other code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an inkling that this might be a good place for exceptions.  Exceptions allow you catch errors, which in Javascript is very handy indeed because it also allows you to execute altetrnative code if your browser doesn't support what you are trying to do.

```
try {
  somethingThatOnlyWorksInChrome();
}
catch (ex) {
  worksInEverythingElse();
}
```